# Corrupted binary download using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Several questions here very helpfully discuss downloading binary files using jQuery and Ajax. My files download but are corrupted. The ones I'm testing are MS docx type but they arrive with different contents and sizes to the original with BOM header bytes EF BB BF prefixed, which I guess means something somewhere in transit is trying to convert them to UTF8.

Test PHP code:

```
$id = json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'downloadfile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
getFileData($pdo, $fileData, $id);  // from database
$file = file_get_contents($fileData['file_location']);
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");     
echo $file;
```

jQuery (I'm using v3.6.0):

```
$('#dodownload').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {'downloadfile': id},
    xhrFields: {responseType: 'blob'},
    url: '/php/ajax/fbdownload-ajax.php',
  })
  .done(function(blob, status, xhr){
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="testfile.docx";
    link.click();
  });
})
```

jQuery says `blob` is 'Blob {size: 14403, type: "application/octet-stream"', `status` is "success" and `xhr.readyState` is 4.

How do prevent the corruption to the file?

Comment: You actually do not need ajax for that. On click just redirect browser to `/php/ajax/fbdownload-ajax.php` and it will automatically download file for you (assuming php is setting correct headers to download file)

Comment: Did you save your PHP script _without_ a BOM?

Comment: @CBroe: You've found it. Thank you. Removing the BOM characters from the PHP file cures the problem. Bangs head repeatedly against keyboard .... Gets on with job.

Comment: @Justinas: true, but I need intervening PHP code to get the file details from the id and to return error messages (in code not yet written).